# How to call async function in sync code and break async/await chain (i.e. how to wrap an async function in a sync function)

Tags: python, async-await, python-asyncio

All my code is written without asyncio in mind; however, I use *one* function that is async (written by another developer; for my purposes it's a black box). Let's call this `func_1`. I need to call this function from within another function, call it `func_2` (which itself may be called in an arbitrarily long chain of functions `func_3`, `func_4` etc...).

Since `func_1` is async, I need to await it, but since I call it in `func_2`, I need to make `func_2` async as well (I can't await within a non-async function). And this goes on an on; I need to turn the entire chain of  functions `func_2`, `func_3`, `func_4` into async functions.

Is there a way to avoid this? I just want to call `func_1`, wait for it to finish, and use the results in the rest of my normal python code. Can I create a wrapper around `func_1` to allow this?

What I want is essentially the following, which doesn't work:

```
# This is the function defined by someone else
async def func_1(*args):
    return something(*args)

# This is my wrapper
def func_1_wrapper(*args):
    return await func_1(*args)

# So that I can call it like normal within the rest of my code
def func_2(*args):
    # do something
    a = func_1_wrapper(*args)
    # do something else
```

Comment: You can execute `func_1` in `func_1_wrapper` and wait for it to complete by using `asyncio.run`: `asyncio.run(func_1())`

Comment: If you care about it being async because it allows *(pseudo) parallel code execution*, then yes, you need to make everything `await` and `async` all the way up. If not, and you're okay with `func_1` blocking everything until its done, just `asyncio.run(func_1())`.

Comment: Right, sounds a lot easier than I expected. Only thing is I don't have `asyncio.run` in my version of the package. Incidentally my `asyncio` doesn't have a `asyncio.__version__`, which surprises me. Would `run_coroutine_threadsafe` do the same thing?

Comment: In older versions you'd use `asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(func_1())`.

Comment: I guess standard library packages don't have a `__version__`, I wasn't aware of that. So this seems to be a python 3.6.5 thing.

Comment: @deceze I tried that before but I got `RuntimeError: This event loop is already running`. Does it only work when it's run inside a function? **Update**: indeed the error pops up when I run it directly in a jupyter notebook, but not when I run it within a function. Gonna try now, thanks for the help.

Comment: Right to those who had my problem: the RuntimeError happens because Ipython runs its own event loop. TO get around it, you need ot also `import nest_asyncio` and run `nest_asyncio.apply()` *before* `asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(func_1(..))`. See: https://github.com/microsoft/playwright-python/issues/178

Comment: @deceze do you want to post this as an answer? I guess it would be ideal to have a section for new versions (`asyncio.run`) and one for older versions (`.get_event_loop.run_until_complete`) with what was discussed here.

Comment: So, correct me if I'm wrong, but am I reading this correct by saying that if you'd like to make that `func_1` function completely `async`, you'd really have to make all the functions/methods within that "chain" to become `async`, otherwise that first `func_1` will end up blocking just like synchronous code?

Comment: This thread has some interesting discussion around the topic: https://discuss.python.org/t/supporting-asyncio-get-event-loop-run-until-complete-in-repls/5573 for reference to anyone dealing with this.

Answer (score 4):

Essentially, you want to start an event loop (the "engine" of async code), submit your function to the event loop, and then wait until this function is done being executed by the event loop.

One approach is `asyncio.run(func_1())`, but you can run into issues if something else in your code already started an event loop or if you are running this in a multithreaded context.

A simple way to handle these edge cases is to use a library like [`asgiref.sync`](https://pypi.org/project/asgiref/#function-wrappers) which allows you to do: `func_1_sync = async_to_sync(func_1)` and then call `func_1_sync()` directly from your synchronous function. Here is a snippet from their pypi page:

> These [helper functions] allow you to wrap or decorate async or sync functions to call
> them from the other style (so you can call async functions from a
> synchronous thread, or vice-versa).
>
> In particular:
>
> AsyncToSync lets a synchronous subthread stop and wait while the async
> function is called on the main thread’s event loop, and then control
> is returned to the thread when the async function is finished.
> SyncToAsync lets async code call a synchronous function, which is run
> in a threadpool and control returned to the async coroutine when the
> synchronous function completes. The idea is to make it easier to call
> synchronous APIs from async code and asynchronous APIs from
> synchronous code so it’s easier to transition code from one style to
> the other.

Another library that does this is [syncer](https://pypi.org/project/syncer/):

> Sometimes (mainly in test) we need to convert asynchronous functions
> to normal, synchronous functions and run them synchronously. It can be
> done by ayncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(), but it’s quite
> long…
>
> Syncer makes this conversion easy.
>
> - Convert coroutine-function (defined by aync def) to normal (synchronous) function
> - Run coroutines synchronously
> - Support both async def and decorator (@asyncio.coroutine) style

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to run it, and the code is already having a loop running in the background, try `next(coro.__await__())`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please consider adding some explanation to the source code explaining how it solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting this to provide information, not sure it will answer everyone's question, and some of it might seem obvious, but this is the information that helped me understand my problem.

#### The first solution(s)

If `func_1` is an async function you want to use without having to await you can do this:

```
def func_1_wrapper(*args):
    return asyncio.run(func_1())
```

In older versions of asyncio, replace `asyncio.run` with `asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(func_1())`

Note that this is a summary of what was written by other people in the comments to me question (@Ajax1234 and @deceze).

#### This will fail in a jupyter notebook

The above solution won't work in jupyter. The reason is that jupyter itself runs an event loop in your process. There are two things you can do in jupyter

###### Make everything async all the way to the top-level function call

In a jupyter cell, you can actually just await an async function directly (`await func_1`). So if you are happy with making every function in the chain you need to use async, you can just run with await in a notebook instead.

###### Use nest_asyncio

If you are not happy with having to make everything async and with having to run functions with `await` in a notebook, then you can do this:

```
import nest_asyncio
nest_asyncio.apply()

def func_1_wrapper(*args):
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(func_1(*args))
```

Normally asyncio doesn't allow nested event loops (i.e. the event loop used by jupyter cannot start a new event loop so that you can `.get_event_loop().run_until_complete()`), but `nest_asyncio.apply` "patches" this somehow to allow you to do that.

Note that there is debate over whether you should be doing this and whether this is safe, but people seem to be using it anyway.

- Some interesting discussion on asyncio and event loops in jupyter: https://discuss.python.org/t/supporting-asyncio-get-event-loop-run-until-complete-in-repls/5573
- Some reasons not to use `nest_asyncio`: https://github.com/erdewit/nest_asyncio/issues/36

Be careful when using nest_asyncio and running a very long function.