# Fast API calls in python

Tags: python, api, asynchronous, jupyter-notebook, get

i am building a package in python. Package will be probably used in Jupyter notebooks. I used synchonized code for some functionality, but it is slow so i am planning to use asyncio

The question is how to implement it with async functionality without changing the code in notebook.
So user will be able to e.g. module.orders("Example Inc")
Now user has to make initial setup e.g.
`loop = asyncio.get_event_loop() loop.run_until_complete(module.orders("Example Inc"))`

I want to avoid this, so it will be easier to use
Thanks
Or is there some better way fo make fast GET api calls

want e.g. module.orders("Example Inc")
avoid this
`loop = asyncio.get_event_loop() loop.run_until_complete(module.orders("Example Inc"))`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Right now user in jupyter notebook call function orders(), he will get some data from server. This process is sometimes very slow (big dataset). So inside orders we want to implement asyncio to get data faster. So in orders function we will use something like asyncio.run(loadDataset()) and wait for data to load, return them to user. The goal is to use async loadDataset and keep orders sync. Looks like this thread helped us a lot https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68744830/how-to-call-async-function-in-sync-code-and-break-async-await-chain-i-e-how-to

Comment: Update, looks like it works in our way, now user can call orders('Example Inc') and will get data from server. Using asyncio and aiohttp TCPConnector is 3 times faster than normal requests

Answer (score 0):

The solusion was relatively easy.
To obtain paralelized get requests with use of asyncio and aiohttp python packages and still have option to use it as 'synchronized code' and avoid async functionality to go up, to other functions.

```
async def getter(params):
    # get data from server 
    c = aiohttp.TCPConnector(limit=100)
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(connector=c) as session:
        # send requests

def orders(name):
    # no need of async
    return asyncio.run(getter(params))


dataset = orders("company")
```

Code above is preudocode.

for usage with jupyter notebbok it is needed to have

```
import nest_asyncio
nest_asyncio.apply()
```

GET requests are faster, but probably there is another bottleneck on the server side