# How to run asyncio.run() within a FastAPI application?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, fastapi, playwright

I'm building an API with FastAPI and Playwright and I'm wondering how I should I write my code.

This is Playwright Asyncio:

```
import asyncio
from playwright.async_api import async_playwright

async def main():
    async with async_playwright() as p:
        browser = await p.chromium.launch()
        page = await browser.new_page()
        await page.goto("http://playwright.dev")
        print(await page.title())
        await browser.close()

asyncio.run(main())
```

and this is FastAPI:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/")
def read_root():
    return {"Hello": "World"}

@app.get("/playwright")
def run_playwright():
    return "Results from running Playwright"
```

**How can I run Playright asyncio *inside* a FastAPI function?**

*Documentation:*

FastAPI: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/

Playwright: https://playwright.dev/python/docs/library#usage

Comment: Perhaps these two questions help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51762227/how-to-call-a-async-function-from-a-synchronized-code-python and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68744830/how-to-call-async-function-in-sync-code-and-break-async-await-chain-i-e-how-to

Comment: Have you tried calling `asyncio.run(main())` from the request handler?

Comment: Consider switching to node/express

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest having a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76148361/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71517830/17865804), which provide details on `async`/`await` in FastAPI (and Python, in general), as well as solutions on how to run another application within the same running event loop.

In your case, as can be seen from the example provided in the question, you could simply call and `await` your custom `async` function from within an `asyn def` FastAPI endpoint as follows:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
import asyncio
from playwright.async_api import async_playwright


app = FastAPI()


async def run_task():
    async with async_playwright() as p:
        browser = await p.chromium.launch()
        page = await browser.new_page()
        await page.goto("http://playwright.dev")
        print(await page.title())
        await browser.close()


@app.get("/playwright")
async def run_playwright():
    await run_task()
```